# How do I select a column that uses a command name in SQL?

Tags: sqlite

Someone decided to name a sqlite column 'from'. Problem is I can't select the column without a syntax error since this is a SQL command. How do I select the data in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the sqlite docs on Keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
>   are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> - `'keyword'`     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> - `"keyword"`     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> - `[keyword]`     A
>     keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not
>     standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL
>     Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> - `` `keyword `` `        A
>     keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
>     This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and
>     is included in SQLite for compatibility.

Comment: [from] did the trick. Thanks! (won't let me accept answer for 10 minutes)